# Searching if a file name begins with String and return results via PHP FTP

Tags: php

Examples:

```
awesome_dksd.php

awesome_dfkdde.php

dklf_dlsfd.php
```

Path to examples: public_html/folder/

How can I search in side of that ftp using php for the files that start with awesome_ I am able to connect via `ftp_connect()` I  just cant find a function or any way to search inside a ftp for a file that begins with `awesome_`?

Thank you

Comment: can i get some help please?

Comment: I think your question is written well enough, but you will just need to have more than 11 minutes of patience. Someone has to both understand and find interest in your question to begin answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of all files using `ftp_nlist`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
```

Then just loop over the `$contents` with `foreach` or use your favourite regex method to filter out anything that doesnt start with **awesome_**!

Comment: can you give me code for the loop?? i am new to ftp functions

Comment: can you write the regex forme?

Comment: the loop i mentioned is a basic php loop. $contents will be a typical array of strings.

Comment: should i use ftp_chdir() ?? @Andrew

Comment: look at the second parameter of ftp_nlist http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try something similiar (tweak to taste and php version)

```
$ftpStream = ftp_connect (...);
// file listing
$files = ftp_nlist (  $ftpStream , string $directory );
// filters array with function that search position of string

$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return !(strpos($value, 'awesome') > 0);
});
```

Regards.